# Hyperlinks within list items in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3, and have written the following HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
    <li class="sprite-link1"><a href="http://www.link1.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="sprite-link2"><a href="http://www.link2.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="sprite-link3"><a href="http://www.link3.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="sprite-link4"><a href="http://www.link4.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="sprite-link5"><a href="http://www.link5.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

None of the links are working. I have tried swapping them around, so they become:

```
<a href="http://www.link1.co.uk/" target="_blank"><li class="sprite-link1"></li></a>
```

Which makes the link work, but then the layout is incorrect. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What's the CSS for your sprites? Can you post a JSfiddle with an actual example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information that you have provided I found that it worked. I changed the one line to

```
<li class="sprite-link5"><a href="http://www.link5.co.uk/" target="_blank">go here!</a></li>
```

so that I had something to click on and it worked fine. The problem must be in your CSS.